# Creating a plsql for backlog history

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Hi I'm trying to create a procedure for calculating the backlog for each day. For eg: if i have a ticketsubmitdate on 12-sep-2015 and it is resolved on 15-sep-2015, then it should show in the backlog for 13-sep-2015 and 14-sep-2015. How do i do that for each day?
please help...

Comment: You've provided far too little information for anyone to answer this question. Please supply your table structure at least and we can generate the SQL you need.

Comment: Hi
 i have columns like programid,ticketid,ticketsubmitdate,ticketresolveddate in my master table where i have to fetch the data from. I have another table for backlog called backlog_history with the same columns and an extra column as_on(for the dates on which the ticket was a backlog).

Comment: i want to fetch each ticket and check if it was resolved on the same day. if not resolved then it should be a backlog for that day and the succeeding days till the resolved date. So i get somewhat of a day to day backlog.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query. It will give you all the dates between two date range -

```
select trunc(date_col2+di) from
  (select level di from dual connect by level < ((date_col1)-(date_col2)) )
order by 1
```